# Trying to access an object with a vector iterator

Tags: c++

I'm new to iterators and I'm facing a problem.

This is a part of code where I create a vector and push some pointers to objects:

```
vector<MyClass*> MyVector;
MyVector.push_back(new object); 
MyVector.push_back(new object); 
MyVector.push_back(new object); 
vector<MyClass*>::iterator temp;
temp = MyVector.end(); //because I want to use a function for the last one
Sum += temp->get_num(); //function that returns an object member
```

By this I want to achieve getting and summing some numbers that are stored inside objects. But as it seems it won't compile.

The error is the following.

> 240    27  ~\test.cpp  [Error] request for member 'get_num' in '* temp.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator-> >()', which is of pointer type 'MyClass*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)

Comment: Read some books or tutorials please.

Comment: You're looking for `MyVector.back()`. `end()` is the one-past-the-end iterator, dereferencing it triggers UB.

Comment: `(*temp)->get_num()`.

Comment: Since `temp` is a `vector<MyClass*>::iterator`, `*temp` is a `MyClass*`, and has no `get_num` member. You need two dereferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first dereference the pointer, before using the MyClass object.

Second, you should not dereference the end iterator (http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/~riesbeck/programming/c++/stl-iterators.html).

Third, the compiler should have warned you about an expected initializer before '+=' token.

```
double sum = 0.0;
sum += (*temp)->get_num();
```